# Retrieve IEnumerable of specific type from combined list of different IEnumerables casted as Object

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have casted different type of IEnumerables and passed them in a list.

```
combinedAll = ((TypeOneIenumerable).Cast<object>()).ToList().Concat(((TypeTwoIenumerable).Cast<object>())).Concat(((TypeThreeIenumerable).Cast<object>()));
```

And I am retrieving this list as

```
var combined = (IEnumerable<object>)value;
```

Now,

I want to separate IEnumerables based upon their specific types.
I am looking to do something like this:

```
var getBackTypeOneIenumerable = (IEnumerable<TypeOneIenumerable>)value;
```

So that I can perform Select/Where on getBackTypeOneIenumerable.

Comment: You mean, like [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.OfType` which filters and casts:

```
IEnumerable<TypeOneIenumerable> getBackTypeOneIenumerable = combinedAll.OfType<TypeOneIenumerable>();
```

Btw, your `ToList` call in your query is redundant, it will create a new list for no reason.

You can have everything together in this way:

```
IEnumerable<TypeOneIenumerable> getBackTypeOneIenumerable = TypeOneIenumerable.OfType<TypeOneIenumerable>()
    .Concat(TypeTwoIenumerable.OfType<TypeOneIenumerable>())
    .Concat(TypeThreeIenumerable.OfType<TypeOneIenumerable>());
```